# Android maven - manifestmerger property

Tags: android, maven

In ADT 20.0.0 (linked from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)) the `manifestmerger` property (to include library project's manifest into the app project) was added.  Is it possible to enable this property in maven builds? if Yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature has been added in the android-maven-plugin and the details are available from the link : https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/pull/135

Comment: NB this is for an APKLIB merge, not AAR.

Answer (score 2):

To provide an exact answer from [the pull request which added the feature](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/pull/135):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <!-- add the following mergeManifests option -->
        <mergeManifests>true</mergeManifests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: NB this is for an APKLIB merge, not AAR.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers work when including manifests from APKLIBs.

But APKLIBs were the precursor to AAR which is the current library packaging standard for Android.

To merge manifests from AAR use the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <manifestMergeLibraries>true</manifestMergeLibraries>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

See http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/manifest-merger-mojo.html